# How to return null if String .contains method doesn't fit?

Tags: java, null, contains

I have this code and would like to return null if there is no Book whose title contains wordInTitle, or if wordInTitle is null or "". I could manage to do that for null and "", but not in case that there's no book whose contain wordInTitle. Can somebody help me plz?

```
public String[] getBookTitlesContaining(String wordInTitle)
{
    int nBooks = 0;
    String[] bookTitle = new String[nBooks];

    for (Book booksTitles : inventory)
    {
        if(booksTitles.getTitle().toLowerCase().contains(wordInTitle.toLowerCase()))
        {
            nBooks++;
        }
    }

    int titleB = 0;
    bookTitle = new String[nBooks];

    for (Book booksTitles : inventory)
    {
        if(booksTitles.getTitle().toLowerCase().contains(wordInTitle.toLowerCase()))
        {
            bookTitle [titleB] = booksTitles.getTitle();
            titleB++;
        }
    }

    if ((wordInTitle == null) || (wordInTitle == "")) 
    {
        return null;
    }

    return bookTitle;
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this `if` to include the case of no matching books:

```
if ((wordInTitle == null) || (wordInTitle == "") || (nBooks == 0)) 
{
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After you count the number of books that have the title, if the count is 0, you can return null;

```
public String[] getBookTitlesContaining(String wordInTitle)
{
    int nBooks = 0;
    String[] bookTitle = new String[nBooks];

    for (Book booksTitles : inventory)
    {
        if(booksTitles.getTitle().toLowerCase().contains(wordInTitle.toLowerCase()))
        {
            nBooks++;
        }
    }

    if (nBooks == 0) return null;
```

Comment: This one get the "missing return statement" error @controlAltDel